# VBA Array For Loop

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I am trying to paste the first value into a cell from a VBA array name Econ(). It has 347 variables that I must check to make sure the a vlookup checks the value then I will paste the check field into a another cell. I am pretty new to VBA and I cannot figure out how to get the first field of the array to paste into the field. Once I get that I can easily copy the check field where I need it within the for loop.

The range of the array need to be the first, I will then paste that into cell I1 then if cell s1 is greater then 0 or NA then I need to paste that in E4 which will have to be increased by one along with the array. For example for the second element it will need to goto E5 and so on as the array goes. The first element can be deleted if needed.

```
Sub Macro_data_check()
Dim Econ() As Variant
Dim i As Long
Econ() = Range("C4:C350")

For i = 1 To 347
 Range(Econ(0)).Select
 Selection.Copy
 Range("I1").Select
 ActiveSheet.Paste
     If Not s1 = 0 Then
     Range("s1").Copy
     Range("E4").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
     End If
    
Next i
```

This is what I currently have but I am getting a error on the Selecting the first element of the array.

Comment: `Range("I1").Value = Econ(i, 1)`

Comment: Why are you even use "Copy/PasteValues"? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba

Comment: What do you copy/paste from `S1` if it is NA?

Answer (score 0):

Pls. try this (assumed that if `S1=#N/A`  the start value is 1.

```
Sub Macro_data_check()
Dim Econ As Variant
Dim i As Long
Set Econ = Range("C4:C350")
Range("I1") = Econ.Address

If Not IsError(Range("S1")) Then
  If Range("S1") > 0 Then
    For i = 1 To 347
         Cells(i + 3, 5) = Range("S1").Value + i - 1
     Next i
  End If
Else
    For i = 1 To 347
         Cells(i + 3, 5) = i
     Next i
End If
    
End Sub
```